# How to set up the image source path properly in XAML

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

i'm trying to put a close button image on my newly created tabs for my app, but i just can't seem to get the right path. This is how i've tried inputting it (code is from MainWindow.xaml):

```
<TabControl Margin="10,26,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding FileTabs}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileTabName}" />
                        <Button Name="closeTabBtn">
                            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/Images/button-close.jpg" />
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This is my project structure:

[image]

What is the correct path for the image source property since i'm kind of new at this ?

Comment: Is the build action of the image set to `Resource`? Does `Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/button-close.png"/>`  work?

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't seem to work, what do you mean by setting the build action of image to resource ?

Comment: Exactly that...You set the build action of the file in VS.

Comment: oh, that fixed it, can you write your response as the answer so i can mark it ? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Build Action` of the image file to `Resource` in Visual Studio and try with a [pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) if your relative path still doesn't work:

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/button-close.png"
```